# Unexpected behaviour with web service API

Tags: java, web-services, amazon-ec2, jax-rs

Developed web service with JAX-RS, Jersey framework. Deployed web service in AWS EC2 instance. Web service has an API that collects data (3MB zip file) and processes it in the following steps.

1. Unzip the file
2. Decrypt the file using AES encryption and generate a text file.
3. Pass the text file to the C Library API which processes the text file and gives result
4. Save the result to the database and generate the response.

Tested with many data files and gave results as expected. But sometimes it behaves in a weird manner. Webservice gave wrong results on processing the user's data. But when the same data was sent to this webservice from the postman, it gave the correct result. I checked the logs file (e.g. catalina.out and localhost_access_log.txt) but it does not show any exceptions.

Did I miss something in webservice configuration? Is there way to find the root causes of these issues?

Here is AWS EC2's details:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
  NAME="Amazon Linux"
  VERSION="2"
  ID="amzn"
  ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
  VERSION_ID="2"
  PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
  ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
  CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
  HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

Comment: Could you show what you have used in "consumes" attribute in the API. Is it an issue with a particular user's data sent from particular client. Please mention that as well. Also you can enable logs at info level for the library and your own code to get a detailed logs of processing in your web service.

Comment: It consumes form datas like zip file , client's user id etc. 10 requests were sent from same client and 2 out 10 request were facing issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the C dynamic library file using shared memory or the same temporary file. So make it thread-safe.